# Build data/class/rtti tree during runtime

Tags: c++, graph, rtti

With visual studios you can put your mouse over a variable which will pop up `[classname]` with members and node names. You can look through a tree of objects, see what values they hold, etc with it.

Is there a way i can dump it into a file so i can easily see it? I had to click >50 times to look through this object and its not a very complex object either..

I am using visual studios 2010 but i don't mind gcc if it has a tool for this task

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to create a cross-referenced documentation of your code based on the annotations. It's quite simple, and will provide the info you're looking for and so much more.

Other than cross-referencing and type hierarchy, you will also be able to get calling graphs, references, and if you put the annotations in your code - documentation. Very powerful tool.

Comment: Incorrect. I need runtime data. The values each ptr and int hold.